# Docker issue with nginx reverse proxying to golang server

Tags: docker, nginx, go, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have nginx reverse proxying to a golang server, each in its own docker container and running normally. I keep getting this error in nginx when trying to connect to Go container, BOTH on my local Mac machine and on the production server Linux Debian. It was working on my local Mac machine a week ago and all of a sudden it doesn't anymore

```
nginx_1  | 2017/09/28 01:29:54 [error] 5#5: *12 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/about HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://67.199.248.12:8080/api/about", host: "localhost"
```

can someone explain what's going on here? What is 67.199.248.12 and why isn't Nginx able to ping/connect to the Go container?

here's what's inside /etc/hosts in Go container

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.23.0.5  31f4103f002c
```

here's my nginx.conf

```
upstream gogo {
  server go:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location /api/ {
    resolver            127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
    proxy_pass          http://gogo;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

I'm using docker-compose v3 to run nginx and docker

```
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  go:
    build:
      context: ./api
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

go code:

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/api/about", About).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Comment: How are you running each container?

Comment: It seems like the nginx container is unable to resolve the address of the go container..

How are you managing networking (swarm, compose, service discovery, env vars...)?

Comment: using docker-compose

Comment: i'm thinking it could be nginx caching issue? but i'm not sure